# Query for distance OR taxonomy term

Tags: query

I'm using a custom query to retrieve posts with geo-coordinates within 10 miles of user coordinates and order them by distance. The query works as intended without issue.

However, my client now wants results to include posts with the term 'online' in a 'business-type' taxonomy. I'm familiar with adding taxonomy terms to a query like this but I can't figure out the 'OR'; that is, return everything within 10 miles OR marked 'online.'

my (hard-coded) query is below. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_5_posts.* , 
pm1.meta_value as lat, pm2.meta_value as lng, 
(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(37.7749295))*SIN(RADIANS(pm1.meta_value))+COS(RADIANS(37.7749295))*COS(RADIANS(pm1.meta_value))*COS(RADIANS(pm2.meta_value)-RADIANS(-122.4194155))) * 3959) AS distance 

FROM wp_5_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_5_postmeta as pm1 ON wp_5_posts.id = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key = 'latitude' 
INNER JOIN wp_5_postmeta as pm2 ON wp_5_posts.id = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = 'longitude'  
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_5_posts.post_type = 'partners-cpt' 
AND wp_5_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_5_posts.ID   
HAVING distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: why don't you use get_posts() directly to build the other set of posts? i assume they're distinct domains.

Comment: I guess I could run a whole separate query and then join the two sets of results but that seems pretty inefficient. Did I misunderstand your suggestion? Everything is in the same domain, same set of standard WP tables.

Comment: well, we don't have the numbers to compare, but you're trying to turn 2 very simple queries into one that isn't.  remember that you hit the cache with get_posts

Comment: any luck so far?

Comment: The client has shifted priorities a bit so I'm going to have to come back to this. But, conceptually, your suggestion makes sense and will be the first thing I try. Thanks very much.